# Based on certain patterns exclude lines in file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

My file looks like this

```
[0.00137532,[0,13,19,16,18,15,19,16,11,15,12,12,13,14,0,11,17,18,14,17],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0189924,0.0871235,0.179813,0.307779,0$
SITE:   0        0.000853196055    0.0694597696 0000000001
[0.00111747753,[0,13,18,16,19,15,18,19,11,15,12,12,13,14,0,11,17,14,16,17],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.018992411,0.0871235198,0.179812517$
[0.000200093646,[0,13,19,17,18,16,19,15,11,16,12,12,13,14,15,0,11,18,14,17],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.018992411,0.0871235198,0.17981251$
[1.9658373e-05,[0,18,14,11,12,19,14,15,16,19,17,12,13,0,11,13,17,18,15,16],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.106437198,0.163778333,0.758483056,$
[0.000282736441,[0,18,15,11,13,19,15,12,16,19,17,12,13,14,0,11,17,18,14,16],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.106437198,0.129806881,0.163778333$
[0.00111187732,[0,13,19,16,18,15,19,17,11,15,12,12,13,14,0,11,17,18,14,16],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.018992411,0.0871235198,0.179812517$
SITE:   1         0.00363901565     0.820587534 1000100111
[0.000647295926,[0,13,19,16,18,15,19,17,11,15,12,12,13,14,0,11,17,18,14,16],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.018992411,0.0871235198,0.17981251$
[0.000272141,[0,11,19,16,18,15,19,17,13,15,14,12,0,14,11,13,17,18,12,16],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.687401201,0.989300937,0.018992411,0.$
[1.82208814e-05,[0,11,16,13,15,19,16,14,17,19,18,12,0,14,15,11,13,18,12,17],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.569817481,0.687401201,0.106437198$
[0.000160613913,[0,11,19,16,18,15,19,17,13,15,14,12,0,14,11,13,17,18,12,16],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.687401201,1.05012976,0.018992411,$
SITE:   2         0.00509457547    0.0291019941 1000000000
```

how can I get a new file in which the lines starting with SITE are excluded (the white space does not have to be there)

Answer (score 6):

Many many ways:

- `grep`:

  ```
  grep -v '^SITE' input.txt >output.txt
  ```

  `^SITE` matches `SITE` at the start, `-v` inverts the match. Input file is `input.txt`, output file is `output.txt`
- `sed`:

  ```
  sed '/^SITE/ d' input.txt >output.txt
  ```

  removing the lines (`d`) starting with `SITE` (`^SITE`).
- `awk`:

  ```
  awk '$0 !~ /^SITE/' input.txt >output.txt
  ```

  Printing if the line does not start with `SITE` (`$0 !~ /^SITE/`)
- `perl`:

  ```
  perl -ne '/^SITE/ || print' input.txt >output.txt
  ```

  Same logic different systax, printing if the line does not start with `SITE`
- `bash`:

  ```
  while IFS= read -r i; do [[ $i =~ ^SITE ]] || echo "$i"; done <input.txt >output.txt
  ```

  Reading the input file line by line and printing any line that does not start with `SITE` (`[[ $i =~ ^SITE ]] || echo "$i"`).
- `python`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  with open('input.txt') as f:
      for line in f:
          if not line.startswith('SITE'):
              print(line, end='')
  ```

  Printing if line does not start with `SITE` (`not line.startswith('SITE')`).

Comment: `grep` seems like the way to go in this case.

Comment: @ByteCommander `sed` is efficient too in this case..